# Git commands execution (like "git diff" or "git help commit") returns errors about "sensible-paper"

Tags: linux, git, manpage

On my Xubuntu 14.04 system I've installed Git using

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

It's working all right (I'm only starting to learn it), but execution of

```
git diff
```

returns

```
error: cannot run sensible-paper: No such file or directory
```

as its first line. After the first line it gives the differences between the files, in other words, works all right.

Furthermore, command

```
man git
```

(or any other help commands, like `git help commit`) returns:

```
man: can't execute sensible-paper: No such file or directory
man: command exited with status 255: (cd /home/max/Desktop/Git Learning && LESS=-ix8RmPm Manual page git-commit(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$PM Manual page git-commit(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$ MAN_PN=git-commit(1) sensible-paper)
```

And so I can't get any help on Git at all (from my shell).
I've Googled for solution, but couldn't find anything similar to the above errors.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: That should be `sensible-pager`, on Debian/Mint/Ubuntu systems. Are you sure it says paper?

Comment: @larsmans the typo [isn't unheard of](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=711510).

Comment: Have you tried updating the system? (i.e. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`)

Comment: Did you try exporting a custom pager? `export PAGER=less` or something like that. Alternatively, run every command with `--no-pager`.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Turns out I never ran Git commands otherwise than through "Ranger shell" (while in Ranger file manager, press S). Now I've tried to run those commands through a shell (xfce4-terminal) without Ranger, and it all works without any errors. What should I do about this question now? Mark it as solved? :\

Answer (score 2):

`sensible-paper` is clearly a typo for `sensible-pager`, which should be the pager executed by default.

To find out which environment variable is mis-set, you can run

```
env | grep sensible-paper
```

To ask Git to use sensible-pager anyway, run

```
git config --global core.pager sensible-pager
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a ***ranger*** problem.DEFAULT_PAGER value is misspelled:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ranger/+bug/1331444.

Change `sensible-paper` to `sensible-pager` in the foloowing files:

```
/usr/share/ranger/ranger/ext/rifle.py:23:DEFAULT_PAGER = 'sensible-paper'
/usr/share/ranger/ranger/__init__.py:27:DEFAULT_PAGER = 'sensible-paper'
/usr/share/ranger/rifle:23:DEFAULT_PAGER = 'sensible-paper'
```